# Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x686) on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: c++, dll, loadlibrary

I am getting below while loading the DLL file on Windows Server 2016 with AMD processor using Java code. We are generating the DLL file using the Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 from CPP code.

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: \ABCD.dll: Can't load this .dll (machine code=0x686) on a AMD 64-bit platform

DLL is working fine when I am trying to load on Windows 10 with Processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10310U. I am new to the Microsoft Visual Studio so not sure what is causing the issue

We tried to load using System.loadLibrary("filename") method

Comment: The issue might not be the actual processor but the format of the executable. If it is a 32 bit executable it can only load 32 bit dll's only. And a 64 bit executable can only load 64 bit dll's. Have you verified the type of executable on both machines? In the end you might need to compile both types of dll and deploy the correct 32/64 version to the respective machines.

Comment: Machine code 0x686 is not listed in the Microsoft list of machine codes. What compiler options did you pass to create that DLL?

Comment: When you say "AMD processor", can you be a bit more precise?

Comment: @Botje compile is set to default